# Local Admin Password Solution showing 1 password from non-admin PowerShell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2019

We run the following command to check and make sure systems have their LAPS setup correctly. We are supposed to do this from an elevated PowerShell prompt and it works fine. When we run it as a non-admin PowerShell none of the computer show the password, which is correct except for 1 and I don't know why. any ideas how to get it to behave like the others?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties ms-Mcs-AdmPwd |
where-object {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*,OU=Non-Windows*') -and
($_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*,OU=Cemetery*') -and ($_.DistinguishedName
-notlike '*,OU=Domain Controllers*')}  |
select name, ms-Mcs-AdmPwd | Sort-Object name
```

Comment: 'which is correct except for 1' In what way isn't it correct?  Can you see it, but you don't expect to?  Did you modify permissions on that one so you could see it, but you don't?  Something else?

Comment: So when running as admin it is correct, I can see everything. Running as non-admin is almost right, I see none except one and I shouldn't see it for any.

Comment: Sorry, realized the answer to my question was in the title, and had a further look. Bottom of page 21 of the Operations Guide covered this; did you check it?

Comment: I couldn't figure out what the deal was with this OU and there was only one computer in it so I recreated the OU, attached the GPO, moved the computer and now its fixed, good enough for me. Thanks